# How to open/show SearchView in ActionBar from NavigationDrawer item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I wanna implement a SearchInterface for my app, however every tutorials I found, just show how to open by click in search icon in actionbar, however I wanna open it from a navigationdrawe item. An exemplo that is the Search from Spotify app. If you would give me a tutorial or a explanation about that, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a fragment when you click on `NavigationDrawer` item. In that fragment keep `SearchView` expanded since beginning.

Comment: But I would want SearchView in ActionBar.

Comment: Yes you can add SearchView in your fragment so that it shows up in ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was to close searchview in my app. 
I solved that by this

```
searchview.setIconified(true);
```

In your problem, You can call this code

```
searchview.setIconified(false);
```

in draweritem click to expand. 
Hope it will help.

Comment: Hein, I didn't implemented already because every tutorial is about SearchView fixed in actionbar. I just want to open SearchView only if a person click in menu to open it. Do you know some tutorial about it? Thx